# How to implement Google One Tap Sign On in QT 6.5?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qt6

### Overview

I've been trying to implement Google's one tap sign on for android with my Qt 6.5.3 android app. I've been trying to follow the steps listed in their docs https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#java, but I don't really know anything about java so I've been flying by the seat of my pants.

### What I've tried

I have my java file `GoogleAuth.java` (shown below), and I try to call `DisplayOneTapSignIn` in my cpp code:

```cpp
   // GoogleAuth.cpp
   if (QJniObject::isClassAvailable("com/test/google/GoogleAuth")) {
        qDebug() << "Found GoogleAuth Class";
        QJniObject googleAuth = QJniObject("com/test/google/GoogleAuth");
        googleAuth.callObjectMethod<void>("DisplayOneTapSignIn");
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Could not find GoogleAuth Class";
    }
```

This doesn't work, though, and fails with:

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

I don't really know how to proceed from here. From what I've read I need to run my java class in a UI thread. I tried a few things in the java class that I found on threads, but none of them work.

This lead me to find this from Qt 5.15 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-customactivity-example.html

### Main question

Do I need to proceed by doing something along the lines in the Qt 5.15 example link above since my java class extends AppCompatActivity? Or should I be doing something via java like creating a wrapper class that runs my GoogleAuth class in a ui thread? If the latter, any suggestions on how to do that?

### Java code reference

```java
// GoogleAuth.java
package com.test.google;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.SignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest.Builder;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.Identity;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;

public class GoogleAuth extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ...

    private static final String TAG = "GoogleAuth";

    private static final int REQ_ONE_TAP = 2;
    private boolean showOneTapUI = true;
  
    private SignInClient oneTapClient;
    private BeginSignInRequest signInRequest;
  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState,
                         @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate start...");
  
        // This is where your UI code goes.
        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this);
        signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
        // .setPasswordRequestOptions(PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
        //         .setSupported(true)
        //         .build())
        .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                .setServerClientId("my-client-id")
                // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                .build())
        // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
        .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
        .build();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate end...");

    }

    public void DisplayOneTapSignIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "DisplayOneTapSignIn start...");

        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                        try {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(
                                result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), REQ_ONE_TAP,
                                null, 0, 0, 0);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                        // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
                });
        Log.d(TAG, "DisplayOneTapSignIn end...");
    }
    // ...
  }
```